# Discord api ignores the 'file' element

Tags: discord

I've got a problem with using requests in python to upload files.

non-working code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/XXXXX/messages'

headers = {
    'authorization': 'XXXXX'
}

data = {
    'file': open('test.png', 'rb')
}

r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=data)
print(r)
print(r.text)
```

This is the response I get:

```
<Response [400]>
{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}
```

so I tried adding to data `"content": "Whoas"`

```
data = {
    'file': open('test.png', 'rb'),
    "content": "Whoas"
}
```

Which will now at least send the message, but without the file.
Here's the response I get:

```
<Response [200]>
{"id": "XXXXX", "type": 0, "content": "Whoas", "channel_id": "XXXXX", "author": {"id": "XXXXX", "username": "XXXXX", "avatar": "XXXXX", "discriminator": "2885", "public_flags": 0}, "attachments": [], "embeds": [], "mentions": [], "mention_roles": [], "pinned": false, "mention_everyone": false, "tts": false, "timestamp": "2021-05-22T09:08:47.061000+00:00", "edited_timestamp": null, "flags": 0, "components": [], "referenced_message": null}
```

I'm most likely just not understanding the discord API documentation (https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message), which unfortunately doesn't go into detail about how to upload a file.

I've tried using the module discord.py with `discord.File('test.png')` but this method isn't giving back the link to the uploaded file, which I need.

If anyone has any idea how to get this to work, it would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell here... you’re using API calls to operate a bot. In reality, this is a very complex process which is why we have libraries such as `discord.py` to make everything simpler. If you’re looking to create a bot, you should totally check out their [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: I do have a bot programmed in ```discord.py``` but I hit a roadblock with the local file manipulation, I want to take a screenshot of a website, (I do have a working code for that, which returns a link to the picture, which is valid for 24h only), so I wanted to download it to a temp file test.png or whatever, then upload it to discord and then I would use ```discord.embed.set_image(url={link to the uploaded image})``` There is no way at least to my knowledge how to upload a file with ```discord.py``` and get a link. And I would like to avoid 3rd party hosting services. Thank you for your help

Comment: I see, so there is a little trick you can use to turn your image file into a valid URL that can be used on an embed. You need to have a separate channel that the bot is in (preferably a private test server that nobody will see). You can have the bot send a message with a file attached (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send). Then, you can take the attachment of that message (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.attachments), and get the Discord URL (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Attachment.url).

Comment: Oh, you are right, that is working, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to have helped!